# Apache POI: Open Template, write, Save as. crashes and creates corrupt file

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I have been writing a program to write names on a roster and have written most of the methods for finding and sorting.
The goal of this method is to open an existing file, write in a cell, and save as a different file. 
I think the problem may be the  template file because it consists of 2 sheets. one sheet is to collect all the names and the second sheet has an image with text boxes linked to the first page to print onto the text box

```
public static void FindTemplate(String Session) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    if(Session.toLowerCase().contains("Level 1".toLowerCase())) 
         // generic roster as an else
    {

        FileInputStream In = new FileInputStream("Directory\\Templates\\A Template.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(In);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Cell cell = null; 
        cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);


        cell.setCellValue("Found it");//just as a test for now
        In.close();


        wb.write(new FileOutputStream("WA1.xls"));
        wb.close();


    }
}
```

When i run it i get a large error that i don't understand. The error is at wb.write(new FileOutputStream("WA1.xls")); I have saved files like this before in my other methods. Also a new file is created but it is corrupt.

```
Error:
 WAException in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/bidimap/TreeBidiMap
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.Section.<init>(Section.java:178)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.MutableSection.<init>(MutableSection.java:41)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySet.init(PropertySet.java:494)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySet.<init>(PropertySet.java:196)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.MutablePropertySet.<init>(MutablePropertySet.java:44)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.SpecialPropertySet.<init>(SpecialPropertySet.java:47)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.DocumentSummaryInformation.<init>(DocumentSummaryInformation.java:99)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySetFactory.create(PropertySetFactory.java:116)
at org.apache.poi.POIDocument.getPropertySet(POIDocument.java:236)
at org.apache.poi.POIDocument.getPropertySet(POIDocument.java:197)
at org.apache.poi.POIDocument.readPropertySet(POIDocument.java:175)
at org.apache.poi.POIDocument.readProperties(POIDocument.java:158)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.updateEncryptionInfo(HSSFWorkbook.java:2295)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getBytes(HSSFWorkbook.java:1506)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1428)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1414)
at rosterWrite.FindTemplate(rosterWrite.java:79)
at rosterWrite.main(rosterWrite.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.bidimap.TreeBidiMap
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 18 more
```

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/bidimap/TreeBidiMap` -- You did not install all the necessary jar files. It looks like Commons Collections 4 is required by POI.  Are you using Maven to manage dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.bidimap.TreeBidiMap`, that means your project is lack of the `TreeBidiMap` class of the Apache commons-collections library. If you using maven, just add commons-collection library to your pom.xml as [this page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2) shows. If not, you need to download the library from [official site](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/download_collections.cgi) and put it to your project.

Comment: I was working on this for so long and that was the solution! wow. Thank you for your help!